# Rebrand Android Application with Domain Change SSL

Tags: android, ssl, https, dns

So I have a problem that my experience says I can't much about but I'd like to ask anyway to see if anyone else there has an idea.

I have an Android app where several thousand users are configured to connect to web services on DOMAIN1 over HTTPS (SSL).  However, I am rebranding the app tomorrow to a new domain (e.g. DOMAIN2).  As part of the domain change, I was planning to forward users from domain1 to domain2.  When I do this, will the web service call work w/ those still configured to domain 1?  My guess is *no* since the SSL cert is different for the new domain.

I will be updating the website and generally letting users know however I can.  However, I imagine there's going to be a lot of people upset that this feature (web service) doesn't work anymore.

Is there a better solution other than telling them to just upgrade the app after they get frustrated?  I don't have any way to message the users in the app itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can keep the old domain under your control, you could keep the old name running too, and have its requests handled by the new service.

If you can have two IP addresses on your server, point one host name to each and configure one of the certificates on each IP address.

If you can only one IP addresses, you could get a certificate that's valid for both host names using two Subject Alternative Name DNS entries. (Some CAs call them UC certificates.) Alternatively, if your existing client supports Server Name Indication, you could enable this on your server and use the two certificates on a single IP address. (One way to check whether your existing client supports SNI is to sniff the traffic with Wireshark and look for the Server Name extension in the TLS Client Hello message.)

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try any of these, but they sound good so check mark for you!